# How to show currentlanguage in string format "English" (not "en") in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode6

I want to show the device language but I can't show in format "English, Korean, French".. I always get this with format: "en", "fr", "ko".. is possible get this with the format that I want??

```
    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var aray: NSArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("AppleLanguages") as NSArray
    var currentLanguage: NSString = aray.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
    println(currentLanguage)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate a language identifier to the corresponding localized display name, e.g.:

```
let currentLanguage = "ko"
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let trans = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: currentLanguage)
println(trans) // "Korean" if the current locale is English
```